django create a record in a table with a foreign key
I want to make a new entry in table with foreign key, through the UI
The Model, Scheme is a table which is referred in table SchemeMovement :
class Scheme(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)  
    scheme_code = models.CharField(db_column='Scheme_Code', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

class SchemeMovement(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)  
    scheme = models.ForeignKey(Scheme, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Scheme_Id', blank=True, null=True)  

The form:
class SchemeForm(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Scheme  
        fields = "__all__"  


class SchememovForm(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = SchemeMovement  
        fields = "__all__" 

The view:
def schmov(request):  
    if request.method == "POST":  
        form = SchememovForm(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():  
            try:  
                form.save()  
                return redirect('/showSchemeMovement')  
            except:  
                pass  
    else:  
        form = SchememovForm()  
    return render(request,'indexSchemeMovement.html',{'form':form})

The html:
<form method="POST" class="post-form" action="/schmov">  
        {% csrf_token %}  
    <div class="container">  
<br>  
    <div class="form-group row">  
    <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>  
    <div class="col-sm-4">  
    <h3>Enter Details</h3>  
    </div>  
  </div>  
  <div class="form-group row">  
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Scheme Code:</label>  
    <div class="col-sm-4">  
      {{ form.scheme.scheme_code }}  
    </div>  
  </div>   

But get blank on the UI:

How to make a new entry through the UI?
UPDATE:
In the html, if I change {{ form.scheme.scheme_code }}  to
{{ form.scheme }}
I could see the dropdown to select the scheme

But how could I display value of "scheme code" instead scheme object(1) ?

Please provide a [mre], show us the code for SchememovForm. Although I am guessing the problem is simply a typo where {{ form.scheme.scheme_code }} should simply be {{ form.scheme }} (Where does the .scheme_code even come from?)

@AbdulAzizBarkat I have edited the question. Table Scheme is referred in table SchemeMovement. The column scheme_code belongs to table Scheme.

What is this Schemexproduct model now?? Please read the [mre] page.

@AbdulAzizBarkat That was a typo. Corrected.


In the html, if I change {{ form.scheme.scheme_code }} to {{ form.scheme }} I could see the dropdown to select the scheme

I implemented the __str__ method for the model.


v
class Scheme(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)  
        scheme_code = models.CharField(db_column='Scheme_Code', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
        return self.scheme_code

The result, got scheme code in the dropdown:

